# Constructing the inverse of the stereographic projection in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to find $\varphi: \mathbb{S}^2 \to \mathbb{C}_{\infty}:=\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty \}$, so let us start from the following fact

When considering the equation of the line passing from the North Pole to a point in the complex extended plane $l(t)=((1-t)x, (1-t)y, t)$ for $0 \leq t \leq 1$ we find the point of intersection between the sphere and this ray, given by: ($z\in \mathbb{C}$)

$$\phi(z)=\left(\frac{2x}{|z|^2+1}, \frac{2y}{|z|^2+1}, \frac{|z|^2-1}{|z|^2+1} \right)=\left(\frac{z+\overline{z}}{|z|^2+1}, \frac{i(\overline{z}-z)}{|z|^2+1}, \frac{|z|^2-1}{|z|^2+1} \right)$$

[image: Projection]

From where $\phi:\mathbb{C}_{\infty} \to \mathbb{S}^2$. But the question is, how to build the inverse?

I have seen, in an alternative [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91431/complex-stereographic-projection-inverse), that if I select

If $z=\dfrac{x_{1}+ix_{2}}{1-x_{3}}$, then $$|z|^2=z\overline{z}=\frac{x_{1}+ix_{2}}{1-x_{3}}\cdot\frac{x_{1}-ix_{2}}{1-x_{3}}=\frac{x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2}{(1-x_{3})^2}=\frac{1-x_{3}^2}{(1-x_{3})^2}=\frac{1+x_{3}}{1-x_{3}},$$
is clear that $(x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2+x_{3})^2=1$ for $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in S^2$. so $|z|^2(1-x_{3})=1+x_{3}$, or equivalently $(|z|^2+1)x_{3}=|z|^2-1$, then
$$x_{3}=\frac{|z|^2-1}{|z|^2+1}=\frac{z\overline{z}-1}{z\overline{z}+1}.$$

But I don't understand that choice of $z$ value, any suggestions? any help is appreciated!

Comment: The inverse function is attained in the same way, by explicitly finding the coordinates. Choose a point $(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{S}^2$ that is not the North pole, draw a line through it and the North pole, and find the point on this line with third coordinate zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, you have to explicitly do some calculations. Let $P=(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in S^2\setminus\{N\}$, that is $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=1$ and $x_3\neq 1$. The line $\ell$ form $N$ to $P$ is parametrized by:
$$\ell(t)=(tx_1,tx_2,t(x_3-1)+1)$$
The intersection with the plane $\mathbb C$ happens when the last coordinate vanishes, so for the time $$\overline t=\frac{1}{1-x_3}$$
and the point of intersection has complex coordinates:
$$\left(\overline tx_1,\overline tx_2\right)=\left(\frac{x_1}{1-x_3},\frac{x_2}{1-x_3}\right)$$ which corresponds to the complex number $$z=\frac{x_1+ix_2}{1-x_3}$$
So defining $$\varphi:S^2\to\mathbb C_\infty,\quad\varphi((x_1,x_2,x_3))=\begin{cases}z=\frac{x_1+ix_2}{1-x_3},\quad x_3\neq 1\\\infty,\qquad \qquad\:\: x_3=1\end{cases}$$
gives you the inverse of the stereographic projection and explains the particular choice of $z$.